# Swift 4.2, UITapGestureRecognizer not working in scrollview

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uitapgesturerecognizer

UITapGestureRecognizer doesn't get trigged in my scrollview for some reason. I've tried many solutions with no avail.

ScrollView:

```
let scrollView: UIScrollView = {

    let scroll = UIScrollView()

    scroll.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    scroll.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
    scroll.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false

    return scroll
}()
```

View containing all views in scrollview (so 'view' is located in this view and not directly within the scrollview):

```
let contentView: UIView = {

    let view = UIView()

    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    return view
}()
```

Gesture recognizer:

```
let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:  #selector(self.viewTap))
            gesture.cancelsTouchesInView = false
            gesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
            view.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
```

Action:

```
@objc func viewTap(sender : UITapGestureRecognizer) {
     // do stuff
}
```

View hierarchy (https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPpTc.jpg):

```
[scrollView]
   [contentView]
      [view] <- UITapGestureRecognizer here
```

Thanks a ton in advance!

Comment: shouldn't `view.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)` have to be `contentView.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)` ?

Comment: No, I want to put the gesture recognizer on 'view' which is in contentView. (sorry for the confusion)

Comment: You need to display your view hierarchy as it is really confusing what you have and what you want to do

Comment: Also add breakpoint in viewTap(_) and try to tap at exact point where your view is. Also, You can open UIView hierarchy on the run to check if your view is actually on screen  - it might be zero height or smth..

Comment: You can also add some color to your view background to make sure you see it first. then open UI hierarchy on the run to check if it is not blocked by anything

Answer (score 1):

Change color of the view (with gesture) to something outstanding like red or yellow. Run your app, check first if you see your view and use "View UI Hierarchy" feature to see if your view is not actually blocked by anything

[image]
[image]

Comment: I checked, it doesn't look obstructed to me ( https://imgur.com/a/wr3tge4 (view with gesture is at the a the bottom (teal colour) ) )

Comment: Can you dump the view it looks like from this tool?